# Removing null values from an array in PHP

Tags: php

I want to remove empty values from an array. I have tried `array_filter`, `array_diff` and a custom coded function but nothing helped.

Here's my code that generates the array:

```
for($i=0;$i<$_POST['size'];$i++)
{
    $e = array();
    if(!@strcasecmp("yes", $_POST['email'.$i]))
    {
        //array_push($e, $_POST['u'.$i]);
        $e[$i] = $_POST['u'.$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $e[$i] = "";
    }
    //var_dump($e);

var_dump($e);
}
```

My `var_dump` outputs:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '12' (length=2)
string '12' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  1 => string '13' (length=2)
string '13' (length=2)
array (size=1)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
array (size=1)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
array (size=1)
  4 => string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
array (size=1)
  5 => string '' (length=0)
```

How would I remove these empty indexes? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: do the key associations need to remain?

Comment: @Dragon
I don't think so. I only need the value 12,13 in the array..so I could later use `implode` and then convert it to a string.

Comment: Are you initialising that array in the right place? You are resetting the `i`th value in each iteration, but it is being wiped at every iteration too. Looks like that initialisation should go before the loop?

Comment: I'm guessing the `else` clause is the problem - that seems to be what is adding the last four empty-string entries. Remove it and see if that helps?

Comment: OP, use tab completion to get your reply-handles correct. The above is @Dagon, not Dragon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you want to remove are not `null`, they are empty strings. You can still use `array_filter` like the following

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($e, 'strlen');
```

We use `strlen` as the callback function because empty string return 0 and is evaluated to false in PHP.
Actually the following also works as pointed out by @revo:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($e);
```

Comment: @revo, thanks for pointing it out. I just assumed it didn't work because OP said it didn't...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `name="email[]"` to get an indexed array from your POST, so you can drop `'size'` and just `foreach` over the array instead. Move the initalization of `$e` out, as you're resetting it for each iteration.

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && is_array($_POST['email'])) {
    $e = array();

    foreach ($_POST['email'] as $email) {
        if (trim($email)) {
            $e[] = $email;
        }
    }

    var_dump($e);
}
```

.. if you really want to keep the worse method with `'size'` and `for`, remove the `is_array` check and replace with your own loop structure, but keep the internal checks and move $e initialization out from your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of the else condition? Simply omit it:

```
for($i=0;$i<$_POST['size'];$i++)
{
    $e = array();
    if(!@strcasecmp("yes", $_POST['email'.$i]))
    {
        //array_push($e, $_POST['u'.$i]);
        $e[] = $_POST['u'.$i];
    }

var_dump($e);
}
```